# Cortar string a partir del segundo "/" - PHP

Tags: php, string

Tengo una ruta guardada en una variable:

```
$path = raiz/email_usuario/Imagenes/Wallpaper/../.......
```

Necesitaria sacar de $path `"raiz/email_usuario"`, no puedo usar explode ya que el email puede ser mas grande o mas pequeño, he pensado en coger a partir del segundo "/" pero no sabria como hacerlo. El resultado final deberá ser `"Imagenes/Wallpaper...."`

Gracias!

Comment: Que tiene que ver que el email sea mas grande o mas pequeño?  Explode funciona sin importar el tamaño

Comment: Cierto, tienes razón, me confundi con otro, el problema de explode es que me lo almacena en array, entonces no puedo poner $ruta[2], $ruta[3]... porque no se cuantos niveles habrá bajado

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo [esta función que fue compartida en las contribuciones de usuarios del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtok.php#87977), en la parte relativa a  [`strtok`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtok.php).

Creo que viene como anillo al dedo para lo que necesitas:

```
function subtok($string,$chr,$pos,$len = NULL) {
    return implode($chr,array_slice(explode($chr,$string),$pos,$len));
}
```

Para usarla en este caso concreto sería así:

```
echo  subtok($path,'/',2) ;
```

O sea, le pasas la ruta, le dices que use el separador `/` y que te extraiga la información a partir del segundo separador.

El resultado sería:

```
Imagenes/Wallpaper/.../...
```

La ventaja es que si necesitas otros tipos de extracciones, por otro separador, o variar la posición que quieres extraer, sólo tienes que cambiar los parámetros que pasas a la función.

Por ejemplo:

```
echo  subtok($path,'/',1) ;
```

Te daría como resultado:

```
email_usuario/Imagenes/Wallpaper/.../...
```

---

Aquí te dejo un **<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/HGLG54728)</kbd>** completo, y más detalles y ejemplos de la función. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Como un guante amigo, fenomeno!

Comment: @FabiánMoreno Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Esto le puede funcionar:

```
$path = 'raiz/email_usuario/test/test2/';
$explode = explode('/',$path);

var_dump($var[0].'/'.$var[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción mas

```
<?php
$path = "raiz/email_usuario/Imagenes/Wallpaper/../.......";
$imagenesPath = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $path), 2));

print_r($imagenesPath);
```